# Typescript interface factorized key definition

Tags: typescript, dataverse

I have some objects returned by an API (namely Dataverse) which contains some keys suffixed with `@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue` so I'm starting with this interface definition:

```
export interface Order {
    mso_name: String,
    "mso_montanthtcur@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": String,
    mso_montanthtcur: Number,
    "createdon@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": String,
    createdon: String,
    "mso_remisemoyennedec@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": String,
    mso_remisemoyennedec: Number,
    "mso_marquecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": String,
    mso_marquecode: Number,
    "statuscode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": String,
    statuscode: Number,
    "_ownerid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": String,
    _ownerid_value: String,
}
```

As you can probably guess, I'd like to factorize that a little bit.
I tried to use template literals like:

```
const SUFFIX = '@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue'

export interface Order {
// ...
  [`statuscode${SUFFIX}`]: String
  statuscode: Number,
// ...
}
```

But it's saying

> A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1169)

I don't understand what I saw on the web about it.
**Is there a simple way for me to factorize my interface ?**

*BTW suffixed props are all string values and all props don't have their suffixed equivalent*